# Ошибка при сохранении в базу данных в webforms

Tags: c#, ado.net, asp.net-webforms

Помогите решить проблему с ошибкой сохранения в базу данных.

Код ошибки:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146232060 Message=Incorrect syntax near 'работы'. Must
>   declare the scalar variable "@Название".

Фрагмент кода:

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='F:\2016\ITVDN\16 [ITVDN] ASP.NET Базовый\[ITVDN] ASP.NET Базовый\006_DataBinding\002_SqlDataBindingSamples\Survey\App_Data\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True";

    connection.Open();
    string sql = @"Insert Into Survey (N'Имя', N'Фамилия', N'Отчество', 
       N'Название конкурсной работы', N'Номинация конкурсной работы',N'Дисциплина', N'Апробация анкеты', 
       N'Уровень', N'Полное название организации', N'Должность', N'Населенный пункт', N'Область', 
       N'Мобильный телефон', N'Как узнали о нас' ) Values(@Имя, @Фамилия, @Отчество, @Название конкурсной работы, 
       @Номинация конкурсной работы, @Дисциплина, @Апробация анкеты, @Уровень, @Полное название организации, 
       @Должность, @Населенный пункт, @Область, @Мобильный телефон, @Как узнали о нас)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        // Добавить параметры
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Имя", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Фамилия", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Отчество", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Название конкурсной работы", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Номинация конкурсной работы", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Дисциплина", TextBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Апробация анкеты", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Уровень", TextBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Полное название организации", TextBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Должность", TextBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Населенный пункт", TextBox9.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Область", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Мобильный телефон", TextBox10.Text);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox11.Text))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Как узнали о нас", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
        }
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Как узнали о нас", TextBox11.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
else
    Response.Write("Ошибка");
```

Comment: Попробуйте в названии параметров заменить пробелы на _

Comment: @ 3per теперь ошибка  Invalid column name 'Имя'.

Invalid column name 'Фамилия'.и так со всеми полями

Comment: Попробуйте перед пробелом поставить \

Comment: Возьмите названия полей в квадратные скобки [ ] в инструкции Insert. [Имя], [Фамилия], и т. д.
И немного не по теме: неужели удобно работать с такими названиями контролов, не путаетесь?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я знаю, что нужно менять названия контроллов, но в данном случае я не путаюсь.